# BROWN + YELLOW = PURPLE

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, alphametic

This is a Cryptoarithmatic, where each letter denotes a single digit number. Find values of all the letters.

> BROWN + YELLOW = PURPLE

Please show your method for solving this question.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Comment: Would no-computers be a good tag for this puzzle?

Answer (score 14):

Firstly we are assuming that the standard rules of Cryptoarithmetics apply

> Leading digits are non-zero and each letter represents a distinct digit.

Here is the manual solution

> First note that if we look in the 1000s digit, we have $R+L \equiv R$ or $R-1$ mod 10 which tells us that $L$ must either be $0$ or $9$.
>  If $L=0$ then the 100s digit tells us that $O+1=P$ (since they cannot be the same) but then, looking at the leading digits, it must be that $Y+1=P$ and $Y=O$ which is not allowed. Hence, $L=9$.
>  The addition in the 100s digit tells us that $P=O-1$ and the leading digits tell us that $Y=P-1$ so $(Y,P,O)$ are three consecutive digits and since $Y$ is not zero and none of them can be $9$, it must be that $1 \leq Y \leq 6$.
>  Addition in the 10s digit gives $W+O = 8$ or $9$.
>  In particular, this means that $Y$ cannot be $3$, leaving five possible values for $Y$.
>  If $Y=1$, then $P=2$, $O=3$ and $W=5$ or $6$.
>  Addition in the unit digit gives $N+W \equiv E$ mod 10 but since $N$ is at least $4$ and $E$ is not $9$, it must be that we carry one in this addition and so $W=5$. Cycling $N$ through the remaining digits, we see that there the only possibilities for $E$ are digits which have already been assigned.
>  Hence $Y \neq 1$.
>  If $Y=2$, $P=3$, $O=4$ and we must have $W=5$.
>  In particular, the sum $N+W < 10$ and $N < 5$ which means $N=1$ and $E=6$.
>  Addition in the 10000s digit gives $B+E+1 = B+7 = U+10$ and since we can only have $B=7$ or $B=8$, it must be that $U$ is a digit which has already been assigned.
>  Hence $Y \neq 2$.
>  If $Y=4$, $P=5$, $O=6$ and we must have $W=2$ or $W=3$.
>  $W=2$ represents $N+W > 9$ so we would have $N=8$ and $E=0$ in this case.
>  As before, $B+E+1 = B+1 = U+10$ but it is not possible to satisfy this.
>  Alternatively, $W=3$ represents $N+W < 10$ which means $N =1$ or $2$ but then $E$ would be $4$ or $5$ which are already assigned.
>  Hence $Y \neq 4$.
>  If $Y=5$, $P=6$, $O=7$ and we must have $W=1$ or $W=2$.
>  $W=1$ represents $N+W > 9$ which is impossible here, hence $W=2$ and $N+W <10$.
>  To stop $E$ from overlapping with previously assigned letters it must be that $N=1$ and $E=3$. As before, $B+E+1 = B+4 = U + 10$ which means $B=8$ but then $U=2=W$ which is disallowed.
>  Hence $Y \neq 5$.
>  Finally, $Y=6$, $P=7$, $O=8$ means that $W=1$ (it cannot be zero by the units addition).
>  Then $N+1 = E < 10$ and $B+E+1 = B+N+2 = U+10$. $B+E+1$ is at most $10$ (given the digits remaining), hence $U=0$ and $B=5$, $E=4$ is forced (since $B \neq N$). Hence $N=3$ and $R=2$.
>  We can check this solution to see that it actually works $$ 52813 + 649981 = 702794$$

Solution

> $$(B,E,L,N,P,O,R,U,W,Y) = (5,4,9,3,7,8,2,0,1,6)$$

Answer (score 2):

[Computer Search](https://www.dcode.fr/cryptarithm-solver) yields

> $52813 + 649981 = 702794$.

Comment: huh, you're also a computer search guy like RobPratt, lol.

Comment: (just recently learned ILP, although this one is an easy search... search "cryptoarithmetic solver online")

Comment: This doesn't explain a method to solve the problem, it is just an answer, not a way to get the answer

Comment: To echo what bobble said above, a useful answer on this site is one that *explains* how to derive the answer, not merely one saying "this can be solved with computers". Otherwise it doesn't help a reader understand how to solve it and understand the process for themselves. Could you explain the steps involved in reaching this answer, please? The question itself does ask for method also... Thanks! :)

Comment: @Stiv should I delete my answer (if I don't know how to solve it manually)?

Comment: Entirely your shout. It's still a *correct* answer, just not as useful as it could be, that's all.

Comment: I think I'll leave it there, at least until a better answer pops up.

Comment: editted. . . . .